# Lookup and see two different cell and then copy

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7

My query is:

I need a macro for

```
IF A9 = "GBP" AND B9 = "GERMANY- ABS" AND NEW CELL = GERMANY
```

The problem is B9 is not exact "GERMANY", it contains some other text so we should use `LIKE` function.

Can you please help?

i have macro or formula for above issue

Comment: When "GERMANY" is in the string, the Excel function `FIND` [MS Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628) might be helpful to you.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried to your post.

Comment: What is your query? If you were looking for VBA code, you can just use Like in If. ie. If [A9] = "GBP" And ([B9] Like "\*GERMANY\*") Then 'You code End If

Comment: Hai , i need a formula for column A = "GBP" And column B = "Germany" then result column c = "Germany"

Comment: Column 1 Column 2                          column 3
GBP          Germany - ABS     ---->     Germany
AUD                  arafas - Australia   ---->     Australia      
GBP                  non ss- GERMANY  ---->     Germany
CAD                  absolute - canada  ---->     Canada

Comment: What do you want saying by "i  have macro or formula for above issue"? If the normal understanding, please edit your question and show them. If not, please correct this part of your question, making it reflecting what you really need. You need to also supply some examples of strings containing "GERMANY- ABS". Do you search for "GERMANY- ABS" or for "GERMANY"? What do you want doing with the returned value?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you can use **FIND** or **SEARCH** it's similar to **LIKE**. Here for example you have two **IF** conditions, where one of them is to find "GERMANY" in cell, modify example according to your needs:

```
=IF(AND(A1="GBP",IFERROR(FIND("GERMANY",B1), 0) > 0),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: _then result column c = "Germany"_ from the comments

Comment: I think he is smart enough to adapt the formula to his needs after I suggested the approach.

Comment: You could simplify and enforce case insensitivity (`SEARCH` i.e. `A=a`) in the 2nd column with `=IF(AND(A1="GBP",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("GeRmAnY",B1))),TRUE,FALSE)`.

Comment: Is it the `SEARCH` that takes in account of the case insensitivity or the way you typed the `GeRmAnY`?

Comment: @Notus_Panda Unlike FIND, the SEARCH function is case-insensitive and it allows using the wildcard characters

Comment: @GedasMiksenas Cheers for the info (forgot to tag VBasic)

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys ,,sorry for late reply,, its working